# CSS - Fixed size regardless of the screen monitor

Tags: html, css

[image]

How can I have an image always covering all the screen regardless of monitor sizes? I have an image which has a height of 1000px and a width of 1000px. I don't want the image to be repeated but I don't want the scrolling bar to appear as well. If I use % the image is repeated, because it's inside a div. Thank you

[image] I want the bottom of the image to be always at the bottom of the browser page and the div/image to be always the same size, even if I zoom with the browser

```
      div {
        width: 1000px;
       left:0%;
    right:0%;
      top: 0%;
      height: 800px;
       text-align:center;
      position: absolute;
     background-image: url("image.png");
      background-position: 50% 50%; 
        margin:auto;  }
```

Comment: You want to zoom in on the image and yet keep it the same size? I'm not understanding why you would want that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if (screen.width>=500){document.write(" body{zoom:78%;}");}

Here's the solution for my code, I needed to change the zoom.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
div {
height: 100%;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;}
```

If you still want to know more, do check out this link
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_full_page.asp

Answer (score 0):

well if you want set up a full image background that is also responsive, you can do the following:

```
div {
width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0; left: 0;
background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center top; position: fixed; z-index: -1;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: I want the div and the image to be always the same size, even if I zoom with the browser

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add this image as background image you can add the below css

```
 div { 
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center top; 
      position: fixed; 
      z-index: 0;
 }
```

Or if you want image to be show you can do the below things

```
  <img src="images/bg.jpg" style="width: 100%;height :100%">
```